# Rename multiple files with regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, file-rename

I downloaded some files from internet. In the name field of those files each `' '` character is replaced by `"%20"`. I want to rename all of those but number of files is too high. So manual approach would be clumsy. I know from command line with regular expression this can be done but I am not very familiar with it. So little help is needed.

Summary is, I want to rename all files in a directory by replacing all `"%20"` patterns with `" "`. How can I do it?

Sample:

```
17%20Clipping.cpp --> 17 Clipping.cpp
14%20Mouse%20(Button)%20Listener.cpp --> 14 Mouse (Button) Listener.cpp
```

Comment: http://www.primaledge.ca/chcase.html  is a perl script to do this, or if you use zshell you can look a `zmv`

Comment: Thanks Doon for your link. I actually wanted to learn to do it using linux command as it is universal tool. That perl script will not be available for me everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can rename a group of files using command  `rename` that accept regular expression

For example, to rename all files matching "*.bak" to strip the extension, you might say

```
rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak
```

To translate uppercase names to lower, you'd use

```
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```

and your answer:

```
rename 's/%20/ /' *.cpp
```

Comment: first define a regular expression (`'s/%20/ /'`) and then apply it on every file that match second regular expression (`*.cpp`)

Comment: No I mean, explain the first expression letter-wise. I can't get it.

Comment: it's better to have a read about re. `s` means change matches expression between two first slashes with everything between second two stashes that here is `' '`

Comment: Be very careful with pattern-based renames. From the man page: _"The renaming has no safeguards.  If the user has permission to rewrite file names, the  command  will  perform
       the  action  without  any  questions.  For example, the result can be quite drastic when the command is run as
       root in the /lib directory.  Always make a backup before running the command, unless you truly know  what  you
       are doing."_

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend against putting spaces in filenames (maybe use underscore instead).  Regardless, here is a command that will do it:

```
for i in *%20*; do new=$(echo $i|sed 's/%20/ /'); echo mv $i "$new"; done
```

In its current form it merely prints the commands it would execute. Once you're sure it does what you want, remove the `echo`.

As @ronmrdechai suggests, the following is an improvement:

```
for i in *%20*; do echo mv $i "${i/\%20/ }"; done
```

The backslash is needed in the pattern because `%` is a metacharacter (match at end) in this case.

Comment: instead of spawning a new process you can use the built in variable expansion and replacement: `mv $i ${i/%20/ }`.