# Partial File Rename with different file types

Tags: linux, bash, rename, mv, data-management

Sorry if this is very simple compared to usual questions but I am just starting out. I have some files all with the same start name but of different file types, e.g:

```
1234.x
1234.y
1234.z
1234_V2.x
1234_V2.y
1234_V2.z
```

I want to rename the first part of these whilst keeping any ending and file type, e.g:

```
4321.x
4321.y
4321.z
4321_V2.x etc
```

I have tried using

```
mv 1234* 4321*
```

and

```
rename 1234* 4321*
```

But no luck! I have also been through all the other SO articles and although I could use a loop, most depend on the file type being the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks all for your answers- it was fantastic to have four answers within 5 minutes of posting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bash substitution:

```
for file in 1234* 
do mv "$file" "4321${file#1234}"
done
```

OR, replace the `do mv` with the following

```
do mv "$file" "${file/1234/4321}"
```

See more in `man bash` under `EXPANSION` section, sub-section `Parameter Expansion`

Comment: Thanks Mircomoses- the first option worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shell script, but it's kind of ugly because it will fork a lot, and thus, if you have a lot of files to rename, it will take time.

```
for f in 1234*; do echo mv $f $(echo $f | sed -e 's/1234/4321/'); done
```

Otherwize, `rename` is a good way to do it:

```
rename 's/1234/4321/' 1234*
```

Rename expects a regular expression as first parameter, see online [documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/prename.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your filenames for `1234` and `4321` i.e constant for all files, you can try this

```
for fn in `find . -name 1234*` 
do 
    newf=`echo $fn | sed s/1234/4321/`
    mv $fn $newfn
done
```

Answer (score 0):

See if it works:

```
rename "s/1234/4321/" 1234*
```

command means substitute(because of `s`) occurances of `"1234"` with `"4321"` in files that has name of pattern `1234*`

You can also look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251042/rename-multiple-files-with-regular-expression/20251075#20251075). It is slightly more complicated than your case.

Comment: But I tested it just now by doing the cases you given. It worked. May be you are not revealing whole scenerio. Would you please elaborate your problem?

Comment: It is strange that it works for you Taufique, the only possible difference I can see is that the replacement name I am actually using contains letters and an _ . Do you think this could make a difference?

Comment: No that should not make any difference. I created several text files with the exact names that you gave me. Then I ran the command and it worked perfectly. BTW do you have multiple occurrance of "1234" in any file name? In that case it would just work for first instance to make it global you got to add just a character in the command.